# How to show customized exception in view using Exception Filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter

I want to display a customized error message in specific view using custom exception filter. I tried below code, and I am able to display the view but not able to display the message which I created in onException() method, or controller Action Method. Below the view name is "Error".

```
 public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var routeData = new RouteData();
        routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
        routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
        Exception exception = filterContext.Exception;
        //Logging the Exception
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        filterContext.RouteData = routeData;
        //filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
        //{
        //    ViewName = "Error"
        //};

    }
```

Can any one help me out please?

Comment: make sure you have modify your web.config and other thing like this http://devproconnections.com/aspnet-mvc/aspnet-mvc-tutorial-handling-errors-and-exceptions

Comment: Thanks for reply. but my requirement is i want to find the exception type in OnException() method and want to display that exception message in the view